# Access LoopContext from Jinja extension

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I wrote a custom tag for Jinja.  The tag will be used inside a for loop tag.  Is there a way to reach the loop context and `loop.index` from within my custom tag?  I know I have access to the global context, however it doesn't contain `loop`.

```
{% for element in set %}
    {% custom %}
        {% include 'child_template.html' %}
    {% endcustom %}
{%endfor%}
```

```
class CustomExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['custom'])

    def parse(self, parser):
        # Here I want to log loop index.  Something like:
        # logging.error(nodes.LoopContextReference().index)
        pass
```